# Why can't I open my file using open method?

Tags: c, linux

Why can't I open my file using open method?

this is my source code:

```
char* dest;
char cwd1[256];
if (getcwd(cwd1, sizeof(cwd1)) == NULL)
perror("getcwd() error\n");
else
    dest=cwd1;    
char* destPlus=strcat(dest,"/");
char*myPathName =strcat(destPlus,fileName);
printf("the path name1: %s \n",myPathName);
char* outputPathName=myPathName;
int d;
// FILE* fd;
if(append)
    d= open(outputPathName, O_WRONLY, O_APPEND | O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
else
    d= open(outputPathName, O_WRONLY,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
if(d<0){
    printf("hello, there's an error with your file, plz check it out\n");
    return;
}
```

in this code d will be negative, why?
Note: the path is true I check it, the error Number is 2

Comment: Are you appending or not? And the value of errno is ...?

Comment: Did you try to check the value of `outputPathName`? Does it make sense? Did you try to check the `errno` result? What error is reported?

Comment: What is the use of all the different point variables? You only need a single array to hold all the relevant parts, big enough to fit the path and all you ant to add to it. Then use `snprintf` to format it with all the information needed. Lastly pass this formatted string to `open`. Also, *print* the string in that array, with quotes at the beginning and end to make sure there's no leading ot trailing spaces. And print the actual error set by `open` (e.g. `strerror(errno)`)

Comment: the path name is true I check it,the errno is 2

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you brother, I'll try.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my error no is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both uses of `open` are wrong:

```
if(append)
    d= open(outputPathName, O_WRONLY, O_APPEND | O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
else
    d= open(outputPathName, O_WRONLY,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
```

`open()` takes three arguments - the `const char *path`, the `int oflag`, and the variable argument `mode_t mode`, which is only used for newly-created files to specify the most-permissive access mode that can be used for the file (as modified by the process's `umask` setting). `mode` only needs to be supplied when `O_CREAT` is set in in the `oflag` flags variable.

You are misusing both the `oflag` and `mode` argument.

A proper use of `open()` would be something like this:

```
if(append)
    d= open(outputPathName, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644 );
else
    d= open(outputPathName, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644 );
```

Per [POSIX `open()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.htm

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h>
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> int openat(int fd, const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The open() function shall establish the connection between a file and
> a file descriptor. It shall create an open file description that
> refers to a file and a file descriptor that refers to that open file
> description. The file descriptor is used by other I/O functions to
> refer to that file. The path argument points to a pathname naming the
> file.
>
> The open() function shall return a file descriptor for the named file,
> allocated as described in File Descriptor Allocation. The open file
> description is new, and therefore the file descriptor shall not share
> it with any other process in the system. The FD_CLOEXEC file
> descriptor flag associated with the new file descriptor shall be
> cleared unless the O_CLOEXEC flag is set in oflag.
>
> The file offset used to mark the current position within the file
> shall be set to the beginning of the file.
>
> The file status flags and file access modes of the open file
> description shall be set according to the value of oflag.
>
> Values for `oflag` are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags
> from the following list, defined in `<fcntl.h>`. Applications shall
> specify exactly one of the first five values (file access modes) below
> in the value of oflag:
>
> `O_EXEC`   Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is
> unspecified if this flag is applied to a directory.
>
> `O_RDONLY` Open for reading only.
>
> ...
>
> `O_CREAT` If the file exists, this flag has no effect except as noted
> under `O_EXCL` below. Otherwise, if `O_DIRECTORY` is not set the file
> shall be created as a regular file; the user ID of the file shall be
> set to the effective user ID of the process; the group ID of the file
> shall be set to the group ID of the file's parent directory or to the
> effective group ID of the process; and the access permission bits (see
> `<sys/stat.h>`) of the file mode shall be set to the value of the
> argument following the `oflag` argument taken as type `mode_t`
> modified as follows: a bitwise AND is performed on the file-mode bits
> and the corresponding bits in the complement of the process' file mode
> creation mask. Thus, all bits in the file mode whose corresponding bit
> in the file mode creation mask is set are cleared. When bits other
> than the file permission bits are set, the effect is unspecified. The
> argument following the `oflag` argument does not affect whether the
> file is open for reading, writing, or for both. Implementations shall
> provide a way to initialize the file's group ID to the group ID of the
> parent directory. Implementations may, but need not, provide an
> implementation-defined way to initialize the file's group ID to the
> effective group ID of the calling process.